Azure SignalR Serverless (JavaScript) client - sending json body to the negotiate API
Is there any way to send JSON body using JS client SignalR library?
I'm trying to find a way to add JSON body using following JS code
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://[host]/[path]",
 {headers:{"Authorization": "Bearer [token]","Content-Type": "application/json","Accept": "application/json"
 },transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling})
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
.withAutomaticReconnect()
.build()

Kind regards
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/signalr/ihttpconnectionoptions?view=signalr-js-latest
Cannot find option to provide request body.

The Negotiate function should be called before the HubConnectionBuilder (with an HTTP request)

Thanks for the suggestion, I tried and it worked.
const InitializeSignalRConnection = () => {

        const headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer [jwt_token]',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json, application/problem+json; charset=utf-8'
        }

        const negotiateReq = {
            'k1': 'v1',
            'k2': 'v2'
        }

        axios.post("https://[host][path]/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1", negotiateReq, {
            headers: headers
        })
            .then((response) => {
                const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl(response.data.url,
                        {
                            accessTokenFactory: () => response.data.accessToken,
                            transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling
                        }
                    )
                    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
                    .withAutomaticReconnect()
                    .build()

                connection.on('Notified', receiveNotifications)

                connection.start()
                    .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));

                return connection;

            })
    }

